# how to fix the solid color carousel issue in bootstrap 5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

[image: picture of the problem]

The carousel looks fine on a desktop screen but when I try to go mobile view it leaves a weird solid color as you can see on the picture.. It doesn't covers the entire height on mobile view as it does on pc . I want the picture to take the entire size of the carousel without the image getting stretch.. cropped image just have to fix the carousel

this is the CSS I have used so far :

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav .navbar-nav li a{
    color: white !important;
    }

.dropdown-menu li a:hover{
        color: black !important;
    }

nav .navbar-nav li {
        margin: 0rem 1rem;
        }    
.carousel-item{
    position: inherit !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 85vh;
}  



.darkoverlay{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.432)
}
```

Bootsrap 5 -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <img src="logo.svg" alt="" srcset="" width="120" class="mx-3">
            </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Services
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu bg-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Photography</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Event Management</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Live Music Arrangements</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Hire Us</a>
              </li>
            
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <header>

        <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img src="images/pexels-ankur-kumar-3872606.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              <div class="darkoverlay"></div>
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h5>First slide label</h5>
                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="images/pexels-emma-bauso-2253870.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              <div class="darkoverlay"></div>
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h5>Second slide label</h5>
                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="images/pexels-studio-negarin-3650469.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              <div class="darkoverlay"></div>
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h5>Third slide label</h5>
                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
          </button>
          <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
          </button>
        </div>

      </header>








    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You’re getting the gray section below your carousel image because you’re overriding the normal `height: auto;` with your own CSS style for the `.carousel-item`, which is setting the height to 85vh. Remove your style override will eliminate the gray section below your image on small screens. If you want your image to fill the vertical space below your navbar, that’s a more complicated requirement.

Comment: how do i make the carousel maintain the same height for every photo ? because the height is changing on each image

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with different size images, you could style the images to `object-fit: cover;` That will cause all of the images to scale vertically and horizontally until all of the space is covered, which does result in your images being cropped on the sides that don’t fit.

You can set how much of the screen is taken up by your carousel with:

```
.carousel {
    height: calc(100vh - 3.5rem);
    /* height: 80vh; */
}
```

You can set the carousel height to either the remaining part of the screen (100vh minus the width of the navbar) or you can use a percentage of the whole screen (80vh).

To have the images adjust, style them with:

```
.carousel-inner,
.carousel-item {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-item img {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}
```

And that results in:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<style>
    nav .navbar-nav li {
        margin: 0rem 1rem;
    }

    
    .darkoverlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.432)
    }

    .carousel {
        height: calc(100vh - 3.5rem);
        /* height: 80vh;; */
    }

    .carousel-inner,
    .carousel-item {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .carousel-item img {
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        object-position: center;
    }
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="logo.svg" alt="Logo" srcset="" width="120" class="mx-3">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Services
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Photography</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Event Management</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Live Music Arrangements</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Hire Us</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<header>
    <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300.png/0000FF/FFFFFF?text=Slide-1" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                <div class="darkoverlay"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>First slide label</h5>
                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200.png/00FF00/FFFFFF?text=Slide-2" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                <div class="darkoverlay"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Second slide label</h5>
                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x200.png/FF0000/FFFFFF?text=Slide-3" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                <div class="darkoverlay"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Third slide label</h5>
                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</header>

<section style="height: 40rem;">
    <p>A section to demonstrate some additional content</p>
</section>
```